# What is the meaning of 'layout-only view removal' in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, layout, react-flexbox-grid

When i wanted to add testID and nativeID in react-native, i observed a warning in react-native docs.

[image]

[image]

I couldn't understand the meaning of 'layout-only view removal'. What is it? Does it have any impact on performance ?